# EF issue with grouping on server

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-5

I ran into this problem when I was doing group by with entity framework.

.Net: 4.5, EF: 5.0, Database: Oracle

My problem was when I was grouping on the server and getting back the data, the grouped data (list of entities) was returning the first record over and over for all the grouped data - but the group KEY was correct.

If I don't do a group by the records return as expected, but I have some grouping requirements and my workaround is ... yeah not making me feel that good and the code should work... but it does not.

x.D = string rest is integer/string mix.

Here is the code that did not work:

```
db.ENTITY_NAME
.Where(x =>
       wantedGs.Contains(x.G) &&
       wantedAs.Contains(x.A)
    )
.GroupBy(x => x.D)
.ToList()
.Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
.Select(x => new MyEntity
    {
        A = x.A,
        B = x.B,
        C = x.C,
        E = x.E,
        D = x.D,
        F = x.F,
        G = x.G
    })
.ToList();
```

Here is the workaround I managed to do what I want:

```
db.ENTITY_NAME
.Where(x =>
       wantedGs.Contains(x.G) &&
       wantedAs.Contains(x.A)
    )
.Select(x => new
{
    x.A,
    x.B,
    x.C,
    x.D,
    x.E,
    x.F,
    x.G
})
.ToList()
.GroupBy(x => x.D)
.Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
.Select(x => new MyEntity
    {
        A = x.A,
        B = x.B,
        C = x.C,
        E = x.E,
        D = x.D,
        F = x.F,
        G = x.G
    })
.ToList();
```

Comment: What is the result if you only execute the `GroupBy(x => x.D)` of the first query?

Answer (score 0):

If this doesn't work, please post some sample data that shows the problem

```
db.ENTITY_NAME
.Where(x =>
       wantedGs.Contains(x.G) &&
       wantedAs.Contains(x.A)
    )
.GroupBy(x => x.D)
.Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
.AsEnumerable()
.Select(x => new MyEntity
    {
        A = x.A,
        B = x.B,
        C = x.C,
        E = x.E,
        D = x.D,
        F = x.F,
        G = x.G
    })
.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I find LINQPad useful in diagnosing this sort of problem. Querying against an Oracle table and switching from the *Results* tab to the *SQL* tab, notice how the first example results in one initial SQL `select`, followed by multiple subsequent `select` statements that are not going to be useful in achieving the proper grouping required. Looks like a bug to me.

This problem appears to be Oracle-specific (possibly particular client versions). A similar `GroupBy` on a Microsoft SQL Express database gave the correct results, although there were also multiple SQL `select`s.

It seems we need to be careful when using `GroupBy` on database connections; it can be both quicker and more accurate to evaluate early (e.g. conversion to a list) so that we're using LINQ to data from that point on.

**Update with repro case:**

First the Oracle (9i) table creation and row insertion:

```
create table payees (
   name varchar2(10),
   amount number(5));
insert into payees values ('JACK', 150);
insert into payees values ('BARRY', 100);
insert into payees values ('EMMA', 20);
insert into payees values ('FLAVIA', 15);
insert into payees values ('SYLVIA', 300);
commit;
```

The good and bad LINQ statements (using Oracle 9i client):

```
var good = Payees.ToList().GroupBy(p => p.Amount / 100);
var bad = Payees.GroupBy(p => p.Amount / 100);
```

An example of a query I'd anticipated an intelligent LINQ to Oracle driver to use:

```
select trunc(amount/100) pay_category, name, amount
from payees
order by pay_category;

PAY_CATEGORY NAME           AMOUNT
------------ ---------- ----------
           0 EMMA               20
           0 FLAVIA             15
           1 JACK              150
           1 BARRY             100
           3 SYLVIA            300
```

The actual strange queries LINQPad reports in the SQL tab, resulting in no useful grouping at all:

```
SELECT t0.AMOUNT
FROM GENSYS.PAYEES t0
GROUP BY t0.AMOUNT

SELECT t0.AMOUNT, t0.NAME
FROM GENSYS.PAYEES t0
WHERE ((t0.AMOUNT IS NULL AND :n0 IS NULL) OR (t0.AMOUNT = :n0))
-- n0 = [15]

SELECT t0.AMOUNT, t0.NAME
FROM GENSYS.PAYEES t0
WHERE ((t0.AMOUNT IS NULL AND :n0 IS NULL) OR (t0.AMOUNT = :n0))
-- n0 = [20]

SELECT t0.AMOUNT, t0.NAME
FROM GENSYS.PAYEES t0
WHERE ((t0.AMOUNT IS NULL AND :n0 IS NULL) OR (t0.AMOUNT = :n0))
-- n0 = [100]

SELECT t0.AMOUNT, t0.NAME
FROM GENSYS.PAYEES t0
WHERE ((t0.AMOUNT IS NULL AND :n0 IS NULL) OR (t0.AMOUNT = :n0))
-- n0 = [150]

SELECT t0.AMOUNT, t0.NAME
FROM GENSYS.PAYEES t0
WHERE ((t0.AMOUNT IS NULL AND :n0 IS NULL) OR (t0.AMOUNT = :n0))
-- n0 = [300]
```

I may be expecting too much of LINQ to SQL though. (My LINQPad reports the LINQPad driver is IQ V2.0.7.0, if that helps).